# Memoization In Python

Tags: python

I'd really love your help with understanding this using of Memoization in Python. I'm new to Python and I'm not quiet sure how to understand this syntax.

```
def fib_mem(n):
    return fib_mem_helper(n,[0,1]+[-1]*(n-1))

def fib_mem_helper(i,mem):
    if mem[i] == -1:
        mem[i]=fib_mem_helper(i-1,mem) + fib_mem_helper(i-2,mem)
        return mem[i]
```

This is a code I saw for avaluating fibonacci number using memoization, what does `[0,1]+[-1]*(n-1)` mean? Can you please explain me what does this type of writing represent?

Comment: The code indentation is very important in python, so please, copy the code in the appropiate indentation, and also the ";" character isn't used in the end of line.

Comment: Please take care when providing code that it is correct. It's much harder to help if it's not. (For this case, that means getting indentation correct, and other syntax such as `:` rather than `;` for `def` and `if` statements.)

Answer (score 1):

`[0, 1] + [-1] * (n - 1)` means "concatenate two lists, one is `[0, 1]`, the other one is a `-1` repeated `n-1` times".

Answer (score 1):

[-1]*5 will create a new list with five elements being -1,i.e  [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1]

[0 1]+[-1]*5 will append the two lists becoming [0 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]

Answer (score 0):

Strange coding, though. Looks like syntax errors. But according to your question:

[0,1] is a list with two elements, the first is an integer 0 and the second one is an integer 1.

A sensible implementation of such a function with memoization in Python would be:

```
def fib(i):
    try:
        return fib._memory[i]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    if i == 1 or i == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        f = fib(i-1) + fib(i-2)
        fib._memory[i] = f
        return f
fib._memory = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to say that even after editing, your code still has a wrong indentation: `return mem[i]` should be unindented.

Among list operations, "+" means concatenation, "*" means repetition, so `[0,1]+[-1]*(n-1)` means a list: [0, 1, -1, ..., -1](totally (n-1) negative 1's).

More explanation:

List `[0, 1, -1, ..., -1]` stores calculated fibonacci sequences(**memoization**). Initially it only contains two valid values: 0 and 1, all "-1" elements mean the sequence at that index has not been computed yet. This memo is passed as the 2nd parameter to function `fib_mem_helper`. If the specified index(i.e. `i`)'s fibonacci number hasn't been computed(test if `mem[i] == -1`), `fib_mem_helper` will recursively compute it and store it to `mem[i]`. If it's been computed, just return from the memo without recomputing.

That's the whole story.

Final word:

This code is not efficient enough, although it takes use of memoization. In fact, it creates a *new* list each time when `fib_mem` is called. For example, if you call `fib_mem(8)` twice, the second call still has to recreate a list and recompute everything afresh. The reason is that you store the memo *inside* the scope of `fib_mem`. To fix it, you could save memo as a dictionary that's outside `fib_mem`.

Answer (score 0):

Memoization is a technique to avoid re-computing the same problem. I will come back to your question but here is an easier to understand solution.

```
mem = {0:0, 1:1}

def fib(n):
    global mem
    if mem.get(n,-1) == -1:
        mem[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    return mem[n]
```

By making `mem` a global variable, you can take advantage of memoization across calls to `fib()`. The line `mem.get(n,-1) == -1` checks if `mem` already contains the computation for `n`. If so, it returns the result `mem[n]`. Otherwise, it makes recursive calls to `fib()` to compute `fib(n)` and stores this in `mem[n]`.

---

Let's walk through your code. The second argument here `fib_mem_helper(n,[0,1]+[-1]*(n-1))` passes a list of the form [0,1,-1,-1,...] with a length of `(n+1)`. Within the `fib_mem_helper` function, this list is referenced by variable `mem`. If `mem[i]` turns out be -1, you compute `m[i]`; otherwise use the already computed result for `mem[i]`. Since you are not persisting `mem` across the calls to `fib_mem()`, it would run an order of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 0):

The speed-up in python can be a million fold or more, when using memoization on certain functions. Here is an example with the fibonacci series. The conventional recursive way is like this and takes forever.

```
def recursive_fibonacci(number):
    if number==0 or number==1:
        return 1
    return recursive_fibonacci(number-1) + recursive_fibonacci(number-2)

print recursive_fibonacci(50),
```

The same algorithm with memoization takes a few milli seconds. Try it yourself!

```
def memoize(f):
    memo={}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:
            memo[x]=f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return helper

@memoize
def recursive_fibonacci(number):
    if number==0 or number==1:
        return 1
    return recursive_fibonacci(number-1) + recursive_fibonacci(number-2)

print recursive_fibonacci(50),
```